# Inversion into Conditional Type

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

**They would have something to cook and eat should their dry ration run out.**
How can I change this sentence into **if pattern.**?

> 1.If their dry rations should run out,they would have something to cook and eat.
>
> 2.If their dry rations run out,they will have something to cook and eat.
>
> 3.If their dry rations ran out,they would have something to cook and eat.

Comment: 1 and 3 are fine. You can replace "if" with "when" to make the second one correct. Another possibility is "If their dry rations **were to** run out, they would..." On another note, in every single one of those sentences, the first part of the sentence can be placed after the second, like you did for the non-if sentence. And finally, the **"If...should"** (sentence 1) is the only sentence that tells you that it is **unlikely to happen**. Do not use it if there is a 50/50 chance of it happening.

Answer (score 2):

Actually all three of your responses are good and show a strong grasp of the grammar.  However all have a slightly different nuance:

> 1.If their dry rations should run out,they would have something to cook and eat.

(Describing a hypothetical future event)  If A were to happen, then there is a potential for B.

> 2.If their dry rations run out,they will have something to cook and eat.

(Describing a hypothetical future event) If A happens,  B is available.

> 3.If their dry rations ran out,they would have something to cook and eat.

(Describing a past plan) If A happened, then there was a potential for B.  Also "would have had something to cook and eat" is legitimate, if you want to express even more uncertainty about their food situation by suggesting subsequent events affected this option.

As usual, much depends on context.

Answer (score -1):

Should means 'in case' here, so definitely not 1.
2. does not use conditional, so answer is 3.

Comment: 1 is also correct, and expresses the fact that it is unlikely to happen. http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/conditional-sentences-2/ I particularly like the very last sentence using all 3 "if", "should" and "happen to".